# GraphQL Apollo Mutation with Input Type

Tags: graphql, apollo, mutation

I want to add the type Task to my Milestone, but I can not figure out the syntax for my query:

This is my schema:

```
type Milestone {
  _id: String!
  title: String!
  task: [Task]
}

type Task {
  _id: String
  name: String
}

input TaskInput {
  _id: ID!
  name: String!
}

type Mutation {
  createMilestone(title: String!, task: TaskInput!): Milestone
}
```

Creating a milestone without the task did work with the following query:

```
mutation {
  createMilestone(title: "TestMilestone") {
    _id
    title
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add `Task` input, write mutation as

```
mutation {
        createMilestone(
            title: "TestMilestone",
            task: {
                _id: "YouId",
                name: "Lorem"
            }) {
          _id
          title
          task {
               _id
               name
           }
        }
      }
```

Comment: When I run your code without the ":" at the response (task {_id name}) it works, but the task is not stored in the document. This is what was saved:
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5c10f6ed9eb3603fa4feb2db"),
    "title" : "TestMilestone2",
    "__v" : 0
}

Comment: @Stef thanks for the ':' and Check the resolver in this case as, from graphiql end, I am not seeing any issue.

Comment: Oh man, you are so right :). I forgot to include the task into the mongoose definitions and the resolvers. Thanks!

Comment: @Stef Cool!! most welcome also consider accepting my answer.